# no such column: _id:, but there is

Tags: android, sqlite

I've created a view in my SQLite database, it contains two _id columns and some other info created by this statement:

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS journeyProfileContactsView AS SELECT JourneyProfile._id, JourneyProfile.TITLE, ContactsProfiles._id, ContactsProfiles.NAME, ContactsProfiles.NUMBER FROM ProfileToContacts INNER JOIN JourneyProfile ON ContactsProfiles._id=ProfileToContacts.contactID INNER JOIN ContactsProfiles ON JourneyProfile._id=ProfileToContacts.profileID
```

and have been struggling with this error for some time:

```
11-27 19:30:04.686: E/AndroidRuntime(12946): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM journeyProfileContactsView WHERE _id=1
```

I am sure that the column does exist, I've opened up the view in SQLite Manager and can confirm that the column exists as _id (the other column is _id:1), although inspecting the cursor suggests it may actually be JourneyProfile._id.

I've tried:

```
"JourneyProfile._id=" + id
"_id=" + id
```

Its really stumped me and I'm not sure where I am going wrong. Any help?

Comment: You can rename them in the View: `CREATE VIEW .. AS SELECT JourneyProfile._id AS _id, ..., ContactsProfiles._id AS contacts_id, ..` where the `AS` is optional. Has the advantage that you can reference them both now.

Comment: Have you changed the schema? Often designers change the Java String that contains the SQL `CREATE` code, but forget to update the SQLiteDatabase schema... Also you are using `CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS`, did you change the VIEW and forget to DROP the old one?

Comment: Yes I have restarted/wipes/cleaned etc the simulator many times. It is createing the view for the first time and on that same run it displays the error. I will try renaming them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with using an old view. I forced my view to be re-created as the table structure had changed and this has resolved it.